# How to use properties to expose a private array as read-only?

Tags: c#, properties, private, protected

What does the following code do?

```
class MyClass {
    private int[] myPrivates;
    public int[] GetMyPrivates
    {
      get { return myPrivates; }
    }

    protected int[] SetMyPrivates
    {
      set { myPrivates = value; }
    }
}
```

Is there a better way of protecting the array `myPrivates`? Is it possible to make it reat-only?

Comment: *"why not have myPrivates read only ?"* Well.. do you want it read-only?  If you need a setter, then clearly it shouldn't be read-only.  If you don't need a setter, then make it read-only.

Comment: I for one think it's always a good idea to protect ones privates.

Comment: Why do you write C# Javastyle?

Comment: @Albin Sunnanbo What exactly is javastyle?

Comment: The only answer needed here is: `lolwhut?!`

Comment: @jessegavin i am agree ! if not class privates are protected any other class could set

Comment: That's free-style. Didn't see that one yet. Two Get/Set *properties* it original. Also, just because the *setter* is private, doesn't make the array private - users can't change the whole array reference, but can still change its *content*.

Comment: @Albin Sunnanbo i am formerly developper of c++ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace your getters and setters with a property this way:

```
class MyClass {
    public int[] MyValues { get; protected set; }

    public MyClass() {
        MyValues = new [] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    }

    public void foo {
        foreach (int i in MyValues) {
            Trace.WriteLine(i.ToString());
        }
    }
}

MyOtherClass {
    MyClass myClass;

    // ...
    void bar {
        // You can access the MyClass values in read outside of MyClass, 
        // because of the public property, but not in write because 
        // of the protected setter.
        foreach (int i in myClass.MyValues) {
            Trace.WriteLine(i.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

You can add pretty much any protection level that is **less** that the one of the property to getters and setters.

Comment: where are myPrivates ?? i am needing to get and set inside class please.

Comment: That's an auto-property. I'll add a usage example.

Comment: is of interest as the speudo code. i look for answer however

Comment: I've just updated my answer for you.

Comment: you have provided time. i shall accept

Answer (score 4):

Your question is *extremely* unclear.

You may be trying to write

```
public int[] MyArray { 
    get { return data; }
    protected set { data = value; }
}
```

If you want to prevent people from modifying the array (eg, `instance.MyArray[5] = 42`), you'll need to expose a `ReadOnlyCollection<int>` instead.

Comment: is generate compile error when i use

Answer (score 1):

One of the best things you could do would be to use .NET's [`auto-implemented properties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx). This is a feature that allows you to declare a property without a backing field. The backing field is automatically generated by .NET.

So, your code could be translated to:

```
class MyClass
{
   public int[] GetMyPrivates
   {
      get;
      protected set;
   }
}
```

Now, as to your more generic question, "what can you do inside a class". Well... that's a really, *really* open question, and deserves a long explanation. But, just skimming the surface, you can:

- Define objects (that is what a **[class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b0thckt.aspx)** does)
- Describe the characteristics for your object through **[fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx)** (a simple variable) and **[properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx)** (a method that looks like a field).
- Describe the behaviors for your object through **[methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx)** (this is the object-oriented lingo for a function)
- Define whether your items (objects, characteristics and/or behaviors) are static or instance. Simply put, **instance** means that you're working on a specific instance of the object/characteristic/behavior; **[static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx)** means that you're working on the whole family of objects
- Define **[access control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx)** for your objects/characteristics/behaviors (e.g., internal, public, protected, private)

There is so much more that can be said, but that should give you an idea of the power you have at your disposal when you use classes in .NET

Answer (score 0):

If you are coming from **Java background** (your *brackets* hint so), you might need to know that .NET has a concept called properties, so you can say:

```
class MyClass {
    private int[] myPrivates;
    public int[] MyPrivates {
      get { return myPrivates; }
      set {myPrivates = value;}
    }
}
```

Or even auto-properties:

```
class MyClass {
    public int[] MyPrivates {get; set;}

}
```